# Laravel 4 old mysql credentials seem to be cashed somewhere?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm setting up my third Laravel 4 project but I keep getting mysql connection credential errors: can't connect with user 'root@localhost' using password 'YES' - with this project.

The server is windows and is running WAMP. The trouble is that no matter what I do it only seems to try to connect to mysql with my old local pc mysql credentials.

I've deleted the database.php config file in app/config/local so that there is only the main database config file. I've triple checked that the mysql credentials are correct in that file.

If I var_dump the mysql password at the end of the database.php config file I get the correct password but var_dump in the connector.php ln 44 still gives me the old credentials

```
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
{
    $username = array_get($config, 'username');

    $password = array_get($config, 'password');
    var_dump($dsn,$username, $password);exit;
    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

Is there a cache somewhere that might be interfering?

Comment: have a look at http://four.laravel.com/docs/cache

Comment: Did you copy files from another project? start by checking public directory's index.php and app/bootstrap/paths.php for possible errors in paths.

Comment: alou - I copied from my laptop to the server. Both use the same folder structure. My home page and login pages load fine, it's just when I need to connect to mysql that the error comes in.

Comment: liam - how would I clear the entire cache?, bearing in mind that I only have ftp access to the server, so I can't use cli

Comment: I ran clear:cache like so:

Route::get('clearCache', function() {
 Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});

and then browsed to domain.com/clearCache

Comment: its not a cache issue - the problem is elsewhere. did you try a fresh install of L4?

Comment: The $config in createConnection is getting either data from another config file or Laravel's default MySQL credentials, i don't see any other explanation than wrong paths somewhere - maybe the files mentioned above. Are you using _DIR_.'/path/to/file' or absolute paths in those files?

Comment: I'm setting up a new Laravel 4  project - we'll see how that goes. I'm basically using the default paths that Laravel comes with: __DIR__... The only difference between my local version and the live version is that the live domain defaults to public_html. But this is the same with the other projects I've done. The config/database.php file does load because I can var_dump the correct password string on that script and it does display in the browser. Very odd. Let's hope a new project will work

Comment: I think what you are seeing is  that the process you are trying to override happen on framework bootup so by the time you are doing your createConnection the model is already using the default mysql connection. Is there a reason you need to createConnection manually?

Comment: I set it all up again from scratch. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delete the "bootstrap/compiled.php" file, and also check the paths being used in the autoloader (i.e. those managed by composer).

Some of those paths (on my non-windows machine anyway) are absolute, so really need to be regenerated "in place".  I think you might need to find a hosting environment where you can get command line access (but that's just good advice in any case :)